# Perl populating a hash from an array of hashes

Tags: perl, hash

I have a script where I am trying to populate a perl hash
I can dereference them fine when I do it individually

```
while(my($key,$value) = each(%{$spec_hash{'XISX'}})) {
     print $key, "," .$value ;
     print "\n";
     }


while(my($key,$value) = each(%{$spec_hash{'XCBO'}})) {
     print $key, "," .$value ;
     print "\n";
     }
```

However when i just try and dereference the %spec_hash It only containst one $exch reference, while it should had two - the XISX and the XCBO.
But it never gets to the XCBO.

```
#!/sbcimp/dyn/data/EVT/GSD/scripts/perl/bin/perl
use FOOConf; # this is our custom DBI module
use Data::Dumper ;
FOOConf::makeDBConnection(production);
my $dbh=$FOOConf::dbh;

my $query = "select e_risk_symbol from gsd_etds where level_name='EXCH_CS' and e_exch_dest='XISX' and e_symbol_comment in ('Bin_6','Bin_56')";
if(!$dbh) {
    print "Error connecting to DataBase; $DBI::errstr\n";
    }
    my $cur_msg = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "\n\nCould not prepare statement:".$dbh->errstr;
    $cur_msg->execute();
    while (my @row=$cur_msg->fetchrow_array) {
           $spec_hash{'XISX'}{$row[0]}=1;
           }
$query = "select e_risk_symbol from gsd_etds where level_name='EXCH_CS' and e_exch_dest='XCBO' and e_combo_type='9999'";
if(!$dbh) {
     print "Error connecting to DataBase; $DBI::errstr\n";
        }
     $cur_msg = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "\n\nCould not prepare statement: ".$dbh->errstr;
     $cur_msg->execute();
     while (my @row=$cur_msg->fetchrow_array) {
          $spec_hash{'XCBO'}{$row[0]}=1;
          }

#while(my($key,$value) = each(%spec_hash)) {
#     print $key, "," .$value ;
#     print "\n";
#     }
#
#     foreach my $exch (sort keys %spec_hash) {
#         print "$exch: $spec_hash{$exch}" ;
#         }

 print Dumper(\%spec_hash);
```

this is the dumper - shouldn't the dumper contain the XCBO as well?
Why does the hash only have the XISX elements?

```
$VAR1 = {
           'XISX' => {
                      'FCEL' => 1,
                      'GPS' => 1,
                      'MCO' => 1,
                      'DPZ' => 1,
                      'WM' => 1,
                      'SPLS' => 1,
                      'ILMN' => 1,
                      'BWLD' => 1,
                      'CTSH' => 1,
                      'EWU' => 1,
                      'MDVN' => 1,
                      'PDCO' => 1,
                      'AFAM' => 1,
                      'SHW' => 1,
                    }
        };
```

Comment: Are there any values in XCBO? Can you include a dump of $spec_hash for us to take a look at?

Comment: the CBOE pull down from the database is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are populating it with those values?

Try adding a print statement in the while loop, something like this:

```
 while (my @row=$cur_msg->fetchrow_array) {
      $spec_hash{'XCBO'}{$row[0]}=1;
      print "DEBUG $row[0]\n";
 }
```

My guess is that your query is not returning any results to add to the hash. Unless I missed something, your other code looks fine.

Comment: You are both correct - the database is connecting, but nothnig is getting pulled down. you would figure that it would throw some error

Comment: It won't produce an error, but there are ways within the ResultSet api to check if the results returned are empty.